# What about a space winch?

Tags: space-elevator

So there is a similar question, I read it but I am thinking a little differently. 
So instead of a big tower going into orbit with cables like an elevator, what if we had a satellite in orbit, something that can move to various orbits and positions. This satellite has a long cable it drops to the earth to pre-determined "Bear Traps" like we do to help land helicopters onto Frigates in rough seas. Once the cable is secured payloads are loaded, the bear trap released, and the whole thing reeled in to the orbiting satellite. From there it is loaded onto docked spaceships to be sent to the moon or where ever. Is that more practical/realistic than a big tower going from the ground up? You know considering the materials are available to withstand the stresses. Would this setup require stronger materials than the earth up tower/elevator?

Comment: How's it going to drop this cable, when it's in free-fall?

Comment: Look up rotovator.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_exchange_tether

Comment: Well an orbit is an endless "free fall" so assuming we both understand that the satellite is not falling to the earth but falling around it the cable would do so as well once released. So to get it started it would likely have to be "shot" out towards the earth to a point where gravity will pull it down, or the end of the cable would need some sort of thrust guidance system to guide it out of its orbit and towards the earth. I would also imagine that the orbiting satellite would have correctional thrusters to stabilize it's orbit against the forces of pulling up extra mass from the surface.

Comment: the same force the satellite exerts on the payload via cable, the payload exerts on the satellite, pulling it down.

Comment: Rotovator is exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: Space elevators, as currently envisaged, are cables suspended between an orbiting counterweight and a ground base station, not a tower built from the ground. -1 for lack of research.

Comment: SF. I think I covered that when I said "I would also imagine that the orbiting satellite would have correctional thrusters to stabilize it's orbit against the forces of pulling up extra mass from the surface." What I meant by this was there would need to be a means of preventing the satellite from being pulled down as it pulls up the payload specifically as well as other stresses/effects the payload would exert onto the system; I am sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: @JCRM how can you give me a -1 for lack of research when none of these things exist and are envisioned multiple different ways? You are basically saying my imagination is wrong about something that doesn't exist yet. Anyway this is way more than I signed up for I wasn't looking for nit-picking on how I envisioned a theoretical means of space exploration I was looking for more information on a spin off of an idea. It is ok if you don't know the answer no one is judging. You can remain silent instead of, well, what ever it is you're doing.

Comment: @TylerVeinot one down vote is not so much in the grand scheme of things. I know they smart a bit, but they happen all the time, it's just a part of "the grand SE experience", and can be reminders how to write future questions.

Comment: Just because they don't exist doesn't mean extensive research hasn't been done.

Comment: The beartrap suggestion sounds a little like the solution in Clarke's [Songs of Distant Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Songs_of_Distant_Earth)

Answer (score 2):

The [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25510/what-about-a-space-winch#comment73957_25510) by @geoffic suggested looking up a rotovator, which is listed in Wikipedia as a [momentum exchange tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum_exchange_tether).

It turns out that this is just the thing that I was envisioning. It seems that in the last half century (or probably longer) a wide variety of schemes for getting to space have been explored in the spaceflight engineering (as well as SciFi) community.

From the (extensive) Wikipedia article:

> A momentum exchange tether is a kind of space tether that could theorically be used as a launch system, or to change spacecraft orbits. Momentum exchange tethers create a controlled force on the end-masses of the system due to the pseudo-force known as centrifugal force.

Comment: you can't secure the end of a rotovator while loading it, and generally involve a high speed/altitude plane attaching the payload to the tether. So not much like the question really.